# Pythonを使ってdocファイルをdocxファイルに変換したい

Tags: python3, macos

ネットで色々調べた結果、下記を参照して試してみましたが、上手く実行できずにおります。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468442/multiple-doc-to-docx-file-conversion-using-python

```
import glob
import subprocess
import os

folder_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/doc_folder'
doc_files = glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.doc'))

for doc in doc_files:
    subprocess.call(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'doc', docx])

error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'soffice': 'soffice'
```

macユーザーのためwin32は利用できないようですので、subprocessを利用した方法を模索しておりますが、
他にやり方をご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけましたら幸甚です。
何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: sofficeコマンド(LibreOffice)はインストールされてパスも通っているのでしょうか？ [How to Convert Word DOC to DOCX Format](http://www.cantoni.org/2020/01/15/how-to-convert-word-doc-to-docx-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

参照している記事ですが、ファイルの変換を実際に行っているのは `soffice` コマンド (LibreOffice/OpenOffice) であり、Python は soffice を間接的に呼び出しているだけです。

実際にあなたが試した際に表示された以下のエラーは "soffice コマンドが見つからない" となっているので、LibreOffice をインストールしてコマンドラインから使える状態にする必要があります。

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'soffice': 'soffice'
```

Comment: ご親切にご教示いただきまして誠にありがとうございます。ご指摘の通り、LibreOfficeをインストールする必要するありました。wordとの互換性が気になって躊躇していたのですが、試してみたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

[Python 3.x - Pythonを使ってdocファイルをdocxファイルに変換したい｜teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/293082)

これではダメでしょうか

Comment: 名前やアイコンが同じなので、本人のマルチポスト先(というか時間的にはむこうが早い)で解決済みということですね。

Comment: ご教示いただきましてありがとうございます。